# Effect of changing intersection normal curvatures on Gauss curvature $K$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

The 30 straight edges of an icosahedron (with constant Euclidean vertex to vertex distance, and constant sphere center to vertex  distance) have normal curvatures $\kappa_n=0$  in radial planes. They span and tessellate 20 equilateral triangles of Gauss curvature $K=0$. We try to find parametrization of the surface in other cases of icosahedral symmetry.

When $K=1$, we have a sphere with all $\kappa_n=1$.

How should the normal curvatures change so that the surface has:

- $K=2$? I imagine spiky surfaces somewhat like the 'Mathematica' logo and/or bulgy ovaloids.
- $K=-1$?

Thanks in advance for a solution or other suggestions.

Comment: The only case of spherical symmetry is the sphere of constant curvature. Do you mean icosahedron symmetry?

Answer (score 2):

There is an equilateral triangle of constant curvature with three equal angles, and the angle can be arbitrary $\alpha>0$. By Gauss-Bonnet, the constant curvature $K$ has the same sign as $3\alpha-\pi$. Now consider the conformal map of the flat equilateral triangle onto this equilateral one, with any given $K$ and any angle consistent with the above restriction. Reflections according to the icosahedron group will give you the developing map of a surface with conic singularities (at the vertices), icosahedral symmetry, and given curvature. This surface can be embedded to $R^3$ if $\alpha\leq 2\pi/5$.

Comment: So in particular what is 3d parametrization for a chosen $\alpha$ so that $K=-1?$

Comment: I did not work it out explicitly.